# Docker - Run Oracle DB image and execute init script

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile

Somewhat surprisingly, I have been unable to find an answer to this, which I feel is a common situation.

So, I am trying to write a docker file in which I would initialize an oracle database and then run a script with SQL queries.

In my folder, I have the following files: dockerfile, dbInit.sql

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim
ADD dbModelAndInit.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 1521
```

After building and running the image, a database is running, but the file is not executed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the user permission on this file ? or checked the container logs ? Note that you need to create a new container during the test i think this will be executed one time only

Comment: The permissions are fine.

The container logs report nothing regarding the sql queries that should be executed, it seems like they are not being executed at all.

Comment: What about the entrypoint itself, can you check it to confirm ? Does it support this feature in specific ? I mean might be a new version of the container is needed which provides a support for it but worth checking anyway

Comment: The command "ADD dbModelAndInit.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/" simply add a file to an image. Who execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and as far as I know, files in "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" are executed automatically, is that right? But I'm not sure that is this particular image "store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim" the scripts placed in this path are executed automatically.

Comment: This was it, I changed the image used and it started working normally. Thanks.

Comment: @Dragan which image did you use then?

Answer (score 0):

---

**In my case, I've had to tell the DB configuration script directly to run my `.sql` scripts.**

1. **Run the container.**
2. **Copy the configuration script** from `home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh`.
3. **Modify the script** by adding the following snippet just before the `## db network set # sqlnet.ora block`:

   ```bash
   # Custom scripts on start up
   echo "====> Checking for custom scripts on startup..."
   if [ ! "$(ls -A /home/oracle/setup/your_scripts/*.sql)" ]; then
       echo "/home/oracle/setup/your_scripts is empty!"
   else
       echo "/home/oracle/setup/your_scripts is not empty"
       for filename in /home/oracle/setup/your_scripts/*.sql; do
           echo "Executing file $filename..."
           sqlplus / as sysdba 2>&1 <<EOF
                 @$filename;
                 exit;
   EOF
       done
   fi
   ```
4. **Rebuild the image** replacing the configuration file.
5. Any all the .sql scripts that you put in that folder will run now when creating the container.

---